# Comma in to kick someone something

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas, phrasal-verbs, indirect-objects

Which of the following is correct?

> 1) I kicked Tim the bag
>
> 2) I kicked Tim, the bag (with a comma)

I want to say that I kicked the bag to Tim, do I need to put a comma after Tim?

Thank you

Comment: 'I kicked the bag to Tim' is idiomatic. 'I kicked Tim the bag' is certainly used but does not sound good English to my own ear, possibly because of the juxtaposition of 'kick' and 'Tim'. But you definitely do not want a comma between the verb and its object.

Comment: See also [ell.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example is correct but perhaps a little difficult to understand. Generally when a verb has two objects you will write it as a prepositional phrase with the words "to" or "for". For example, "I kicked the bag to Tim". However when one of the objects is a pronoun, you can put both objects next to each other, for example "I kicked him the bag". [This page has more examples.](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/double-object-verbs) The second sentence looks to me as if you kicked both Tim and the bag.

Comment: I would say that 'Tim' is the indirect object in the dative case - 'to Tim'.